# Print data QTextDocument and QPainter

Tags: c++, qt

How can I print the `html` data using `QTextDocument`?

My code, but returns error:

```
QString text_x = "Hello World!";

QTextDocument *doc = new QTextDocument(this);
doc->setUndoRedoEnabled(false);
doc->setHtml("<p><span style=\"color:#000000; font-weight:600\">"+text_x+"</span></p>");
doc->setTextWidth(width());
doc->setUseDesignMetrics(true);
doc->setDefaultTextOption(QTextOption(Qt::AlignHCenter));

QPainter *p = new QPainter(this);
p->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
p->begin(this);
doc->drawContents(p);
p->end();
```

Error:

> QPainter::pen: Painter not active QPainter::setPen: Painter not active QPainter::pen: Painter not active QPainter::setPen: Painter not active QPainter::setPen: Painter not active QPainter::setPen: Painter not active QPainter::restore: Unbalanced save/restore QPainter::end: Painter not active, aborted

Comment: What is the `this` points in your example to?

Comment: @vahancho How do I use `QPainter::begin()` ?

Comment: you are drawing on widget outside `paintEvent` and this is a problem.

Comment: @Marek R how can I use the `paintEvent`, please could show me the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I wrote in comment: you are drawing on widget outside `paintEvent` and this is a problem.

Here is example code as you ask:

```
class MyDocWidget : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyDocWidget(QWidget * parent = 0, Qt::WindowFlags f = 0)
         : QWidget(parent, f)
    {
        doc = new QTextDocument(this);
        doc->setUndoRedoEnabled(false);
    }

public slots:
    void setHtml(const QString &html) {
         doc->setHtml(html);
         update();
    }

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event) {
         QPainter p(this);
         p.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
         doc->drawContents(&p);
    }

    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent * event) {
         QWidget::resizeEvent(event);
         doc->setTextWidth(width());
         update();
    }

private:
    QTextDocument *doc;
}
```